# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to load native library: /data/app-lib/com.gibucsoft.blocklife-1/libblocklife.so

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I'm trying to compile an Android NDK project and I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gibucsoft.blocklife/com.gibucsoft.blocklife.MtNativeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to load native library: /data/app-lib/com.gibucsoft.blocklife-1/libblocklife.so
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2235)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2285)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1236)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5061)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:603)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to load native library: /data/app-lib/com.gibucsoft.blocklife-1/libblocklife.so
        at android.app.NativeActivity.onCreate(NativeActivity.java:183)
        at com.gibucsoft.blocklife.MtNativeActivity.onCreate(MtNativeActivity.java:12)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2285)  
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1236)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5061)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:603)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I tried to find some solution and I found some questions with similar error but no solution worked for me.
Here is AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gibucsoft.blocklife"
    android:versionCode="12"
    android:versionName="1.1..12"
    android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"/>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00010000"     android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission     android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission     android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/irr_icon"     android:label="Blocklife"     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"     android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name=".MtNativeActivity"
        android:label="Blocklife"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"     android:value="blocklife" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".BlocklifeTextEntry"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".BlocklifeAssetCopy"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true">
    </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And here Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)/..

#LOCAL_ADDRESS_SANITIZER:=true

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := Irrlicht
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := deps/irrlicht/lib/Android/libIrrlicht.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

ifeq ($(HAVE_LEVELDB), 1)
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_MODULE := LevelDB
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := deps/leveldb/libleveldb.a
    include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
endif

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := curl
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := deps/curl/lib/.libs/libcurl.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := freetype
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := deps/freetype2-android/Android/obj/local/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libfreetype2-static.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := openal
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := deps/openal-soft/libs/$(TARGET_LIBDIR)/libopenal.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := ogg
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := deps/libvorbis-libogg-android/libs/$(TARGET_LIBDIR)/libogg.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := vorbis
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := deps/libvorbis-libogg-android/libs/$(TARGET_LIBDIR)/libvorbis.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := gmp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := deps/gmp/usr/lib/libgmp.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := ssl
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := deps/openssl/libssl.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := crypto
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := deps/openssl/libcrypto.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := blocklife

LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += exceptions

ifdef GPROF
GPROF_DEF=-DGPROF
endif

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -D_IRR_ANDROID_PLATFORM_      \
                -DHAVE_TOUCHSCREENGUI         \
                -DUSE_CURL=1                  \
                -DUSE_SOUND=1                 \
                -DUSE_FREETYPE=1              \
                -DUSE_LEVELDB=$(HAVE_LEVELDB) \
                $(GPROF_DEF)                  \
                -pipe -fstrict-aliasing

ifndef NDEBUG
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -g -D_DEBUG -O0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer
else
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fexpensive-optimizations -O3
endif

ifdef GPROF
PROFILER_LIBS := android-ndk-profiler
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -pg
endif

# LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fsanitize=address
# LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -fsanitize=address

ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86)
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fno-stack-protector
endif

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES :=                               \
        jni/src jni/src/sqlite                    \
        jni/src/script                            \
        jni/src/lua/src                           \
        jni/src/json                              \
        jni/src/cguittfont                        \
        deps/irrlicht/include                     \
        deps/freetype2-android/include            \
        deps/curl/include                         \
        deps/openal-soft/jni/OpenAL/include       \
        deps/libvorbis-libogg-android/jni/include \
        deps/gmp/usr/include                      \
        deps/leveldb/include                      \
        deps/sqlite/

LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=                                \
        jni/src/ban.cpp                           \
        jni/src/base64.cpp                          \
        jni/src/biome.cpp                           \
        jni/src/camera.cpp                        \
        jni/src/cavegen.cpp                       \
        jni/src/chat.cpp                          \
        jni/src/client.cpp                        \
        jni/src/clientmap.cpp                     \
        jni/src/clientobject.cpp                  \
        jni/src/clientserver.cpp                    \
        jni/src/clouds.cpp                        \
        jni/src/collision.cpp                     \
        jni/src/connection.cpp                  \
        jni/src/content_abm.cpp                   \
        jni/src/content_cao.cpp                   \
        jni/src/content_cso.cpp                   \
        jni/src/content_mapblock.cpp              \
        jni/src/content_mapnode.cpp               \
        jni/src/content_nodemeta.cpp              \
        jni/src/content_sao.cpp                   \
        jni/src/craftdef.cpp                      \
        jni/src/database-dummy.cpp                \
        jni/src/database-sqlite3.cpp              \
        jni/src/database.cpp                      \
        jni/src/debug.cpp                         \
        jni/src/defaultsettings.cpp               \
        jni/src/dungeongen.cpp                    \
        jni/src/emerge.cpp                        \
        jni/src/environment.cpp                   \
        jni/src/farmesh.cpp                         \
        jni/src/filecache.cpp                     \
        jni/src/filesys.cpp                       \
        jni/src/game.cpp                          \
        jni/src/genericobject.cpp                 \
        jni/src/guiChatConsole.cpp                \
        jni/src/guiConfigureWorld.cpp               \
        jni/src/guiConfirmMenu.cpp                  \
        jni/src/guiCreateWorld.cpp                  \
        jni/src/guiDeathScreen.cpp                  \
        jni/src/guiFormSpecMenu.cpp               \
        jni/src/guiKeyChangeMenu.cpp              \
        jni/src/guiMainMenu.cpp                     \
        jni/src/guiMessageMenu.cpp                  \
        jni/src/guiPasswordChange.cpp             \
        jni/src/guiPauseMenu.cpp                \
        jni/src/guiTextInputMenu.cpp                \
        jni/src/guiVolumeChange.cpp               \
        jni/src/hud.cpp                           \
        jni/src/inventory.cpp                     \
        jni/src/inventorymanager.cpp              \
        jni/src/itemdef.cpp                       \
        jni/src/keycode.cpp                       \
        jni/src/light.cpp                         \
        jni/src/localplayer.cpp                   \
        jni/src/log.cpp                           \
        jni/src/main.cpp                          \
        jni/src/map.cpp                           \
        jni/src/mapblock.cpp                      \
        jni/src/mapblock_mesh.cpp                 \
        jni/src/mapgen.cpp                        \
        jni/src/mapgen_indev.cpp                \
        jni/src/mapgen_math.cpp                 \
        jni/src/mapgen_singlenode.cpp             \
        jni/src/mapgen_v6.cpp                     \
        jni/src/mapgen_v7.cpp                     \
        jni/src/mapnode.cpp                       \
        jni/src/mapsector.cpp                     \
        jni/src/mesh.cpp                          \
        jni/src/mods.cpp                          \
        jni/src/nameidmapping.cpp                 \
        jni/src/nodedef.cpp                       \
        jni/src/nodemetadata.cpp                  \
        jni/src/nodetimer.cpp                     \
        jni/src/noise.cpp                         \
        jni/src/object_properties.cpp             \
        jni/src/particles.cpp                     \
        jni/src/pathfinder.cpp                    \
        jni/src/player.cpp                        \
        jni/src/porting.cpp                       \
        jni/src/quicktune.cpp                     \
        jni/src/rollback.cpp                      \
        jni/src/rollback_interface.cpp            \
        jni/src/serialization.cpp                 \
        jni/src/server.cpp                        \
        jni/src/serverlist.cpp                    \
        jni/src/serverobject.cpp                  \
        jni/src/shader.cpp                        \
        jni/src/sha1.cpp                          \
        jni/src/sky.cpp                           \
        jni/src/socket.cpp                        \
        jni/src/sound.cpp                         \
        jni/src/sound_openal.cpp                  \
        jni/src/staticobject.cpp                  \
        jni/src/subgame.cpp                       \
        jni/src/tool.cpp                          \
        jni/src/treegen.cpp                       \
        jni/src/voxel.cpp                         \
        jni/src/voxelalgorithms.cpp               \
        jni/src/util/directiontables.cpp          \
        jni/src/util/numeric.cpp                  \
        jni/src/util/pointedthing.cpp             \
        jni/src/util/serialize.cpp                \
        jni/src/util/string.cpp                   \
        jni/src/util/timetaker.cpp                \
        jni/src/test.cpp                            \
        jni/src/tile.cpp      

# lua api
LOCAL_SRC_FILES +=                                \
        jni/src/script/common/c_content.cpp       \
        jni/src/script/common/c_converter.cpp     \
        jni/src/script/common/c_internal.cpp      \
        jni/src/script/common/c_types.cpp         \
        jni/src/script/cpp_api/s_base.cpp         \
        jni/src/script/cpp_api/s_entity.cpp       \
        jni/src/script/cpp_api/s_env.cpp          \
        jni/src/script/cpp_api/s_inventory.cpp    \
        jni/src/script/cpp_api/s_item.cpp         \
        jni/src/script/cpp_api/s_node.cpp         \
        jni/src/script/cpp_api/s_nodemeta.cpp     \
        jni/src/script/cpp_api/s_player.cpp       \
        jni/src/script/cpp_api/scriptapi.cpp       \
        jni/src/script/lua_api/l_base.cpp         \
        jni/src/script/lua_api/l_craft.cpp        \
        jni/src/script/lua_api/l_env.cpp          \
        jni/src/script/lua_api/l_inventory.cpp    \
        jni/src/script/lua_api/l_item.cpp         \
        jni/src/script/lua_api/l_nodemeta.cpp     \
        jni/src/script/lua_api/l_nodetimer.cpp    \
        jni/src/script/lua_api/l_noise.cpp        \
        jni/src/script/lua_api/l_object.cpp       \
        jni/src/script/lua_api/l_particles.cpp    

#freetype2 support
LOCAL_SRC_FILES +=                                \
        jni/src/cguittfont/xCGUITTFont.cpp

# lua
LOCAL_SRC_FILES +=                                \
        jni/src/lua/src/lapi.c                    \
        jni/src/lua/src/lauxlib.c                 \
        jni/src/lua/src/lbaselib.c                \
        jni/src/lua/src/lcode.c                   \
        jni/src/lua/src/ldblib.c                  \
        jni/src/lua/src/ldebug.c                  \
        jni/src/lua/src/ldo.c                     \
        jni/src/lua/src/ldump.c                   \
        jni/src/lua/src/lfunc.c                   \
        jni/src/lua/src/lgc.c                     \
        jni/src/lua/src/linit.c                   \
        jni/src/lua/src/liolib.c                  \
        jni/src/lua/src/llex.c                    \
        jni/src/lua/src/lmathlib.c                \
        jni/src/lua/src/lmem.c                    \
        jni/src/lua/src/loadlib.c                 \
        jni/src/lua/src/lobject.c                 \
        jni/src/lua/src/lopcodes.c                \
        jni/src/lua/src/loslib.c                  \
        jni/src/lua/src/lparser.c                 \
        jni/src/lua/src/lstate.c                  \
        jni/src/lua/src/lstring.c                 \
        jni/src/lua/src/lstrlib.c                 \
        jni/src/lua/src/ltable.c                  \
        jni/src/lua/src/ltablib.c                 \
        jni/src/lua/src/ltm.c                     \
        jni/src/lua/src/lundump.c                 \
        jni/src/lua/src/lvm.c                     \
        jni/src/lua/src/lzio.c                    \
        jni/src/lua/src/print.c

# sqlite
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += deps/sqlite/sqlite3.c

# jthread
LOCAL_SRC_FILES +=                                \
        jni/src/jthread/pthread/jmutex.cpp        \
        jni/src/jthread/pthread/jthread.cpp

# json
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += jni/src/json/jsoncpp.cpp

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := openal ogg vorbis gmp blocklife
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := Irrlicht freetype curl ssl crypto android_native_app_glue $(PROFILER_LIBS)

ifeq ($(HAVE_LEVELDB), 1)
    LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += LevelDB
endif
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lEGL -llog -lGLESv1_CM -lGLESv2 -lz -landroid

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# at the end of Android.mk
ifdef GPROF
$(call import-module,android-ndk-profiler)
endif
$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
```

And here Application.mk:

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-9
APP_MODULES := blocklife
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions
APP_GNUSTL_FORCE_CPP_FEATURES := rtti
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to put the `app_dummy()` command in the `void android_main(struct android_app* state)` function.

Comment: Gah, yes!  Thanks a million.

Comment: what is the "android entry function", where does app_dummy() go in the code above?